# Body css style overriding h2 css style

Tags: typescript, react-tsx

I have created the following:

```
return (
<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <h1>WEEKLY FOOT-QUIZ</h1>
  </header>

  <body className="App-body">
    <h2 className='App-title'>Welcome To The Weekly Football Quiz</h2>

  </body>
</div>
 );
```

and my css looks like:

```
.App-title {
  color: blue;
  justify-content: left;
}

.App-body {
  background-color: #fefbe9;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? .App-body seems to override anything from .App-title.

Using typescript with react.

Comment: you should be able to do `justify-content: left !important;` to force it

Comment: @Nikster still seems to remain the same spot.

Answer (score 1):

Placing the App-title css after App-body will do the job.

Comment: ah that was simple haha I tried that earlier works now thanks! However, it changes the colour but property like justify-content: left; does not do anything. Any reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a more specific selector when you want more specific styles to override.  Styles will cascade from parent elements into child elements.  CSS doesn't look for the style *nearest* to an element, rather it looks for the most specific selector.  In your selectors, you're referencing each element with a single class selector - these have the same level of specificity (a single class).  If you change `.App-title` to `.App-body .App-title`, this will give it increased specificity over the `.App-body` selector.

Changing their order works as well, because after specificity order is the next determiner in which style applies.  But generally, order it is not good to rely on order in a large application, because it's easy for it to change.

Here's more information on specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity